# MATLAB command for checking images on the web

Tags: image, matlab, web, command

I've tried the following

```
url=[http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/c/ce/Who_Killed_the_Electric_Car.jpg];
filename = [teste.jpg]
urlwrite (url, filename)
```

By doing these steps, the image in this link will be written under "teste.jpg" filename

In other hand, if I try:

```
url=[http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/c/ce/ererr.jpg];
filename = [teste.jpg]
urlwrite (url, filename)
```

Matlab prompt will return :

> ??? Error using ==> urlwrite at 140 Error downloading URL. Your
>   network connection may be down or your proxy settings improperly
>   configured.

So, how can I make matlab to check if the image exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use output arguments, the error will be suppressed. See [URLWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlwrite.html) documentation.

> **[filestr,status] = urlwrite(*_*)** stores the file path in variable filestr, and suppresses the display of error messages, using any of
>   the input arguments in the previous syntaxes. When the operation is
>   successful, status is 1. Otherwise, status is 0.